# Signed jar file not recognized java u_121

Tags: java, jar, signed

A JNDI application signed with a Digicert certificate stopped working with the release of Java update 121.

When upgraded my JDK and ran jarsigner it was not verified,

jarsigner -verify -verbose myApp.jar
yielded

Unparsable signature-related file META-INF/SERVER.RSA

the previous version of jarsigner verified the same jar file verified it.

Answer (score 1):

Un-signing, then resigning the jars using the newer version of jarsigner fixed the problem